# Subsetting a data frame based on argument n+

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of various products and their respective cost. I have a function that subsets the dataframe rows using the argument 'n'. For example, if n=6, 6 rows will be returned. This, however, means that the 7th row (which may have the same price as the 6th) is not given in the output.

I want to be able to subset the df based on n, but at the same time return any additional rows that have the same cost as a row within the subset.

I've so far got this.

It returns a data frame of 5 rows (n=4 + 1 as the price of 5th row is the same as the 4th row) but I want to get it so that it returns 6 rows if the 6th row price is also the same.

I hope this makes sense, it's very messy and convoluted- I'm new to this so any help would be hugely appreciated!

```py
def most_expensive_items(n): 
    subsetted_cost=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n]
    test1_df=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n+1]
    test2_df=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n+2]
    test3_df=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n+3]
    test4_df=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n+4]
    test5_df=COST_DF.sort_values(by=["cost"], ascending=False)[:n+5]

    for r in COST_DF:
        for _, row_q in test1_df.iterrows():
            cost1= (test1_df.iloc[-1])
            for _, row_s in test2_df.iterrows():
                cost2= (test2_df.iloc[-1])
                for _, row_p in test3_df.iterrows():
                    cost3= (test3_df.iloc[-1])
                    for _, row_t in subsetted_cost.iterrows():
                        cost_last_row= (subsetted_cost.iloc[-1])
                    
        if cost1.cost == cost_last_row.cost:
            return subsetted_cost.append(cost1)
        if cost2.cost == cost_last_row.cost:
            return subsetted_cost.append(cost1, cost2)
        if cost3.cost == cost_last_row.cost:
            return subsetted_cost.append(cost1, cost2, cost3)
            
most_expensive_items(4)
```

Comment: *EDIT* 'For example, if n=6, 3 rows will be returned' ----> should be 6 instead of 3!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

Example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

# random integer costs between 0 and 5 (non-inclusive)
cost = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10))

# 10 unique items with associated costs
df = pd.DataFrame({"item": list("abcdefghij"), "cost": cost})

# original
print(df)
```

```
  item  cost
0    a     4
1    b     0
2    c     3
3    d     3
4    e     3
5    f     1
6    g     3
7    h     2
8    i     4
9    j     0
```

```py
# return the 3 items with the highest costs, but keep any if there are ties
print(df.loc[df.cost.nlargest(3, keep="all").index])
```

```
  item  cost
0    a     4
8    i     4
2    c     3
3    d     3
4    e     3
6    g     3
```

## Or maybe...

you want the top N costs, and the items for each?

Something like this could work

```py
print(df.loc[df.cost.isin(df.cost.drop_duplicates().nlargest(3))])
```

```
  item  cost
0    a     4
2    c     3
3    d     3
4    e     3
6    g     3
7    h     2
8    i     4
```

Could also do this if you don't mind the item names being in an array

```py
print(df.groupby("cost").item.unique().tail(3))
```

```
cost
2             [h]
3    [c, d, e, g]
4          [a, i]
```

But if you do we can quickly get back to a frame

```py
print(df.groupby("cost").item.unique().tail(3).explode().reset_index())
```

```
   cost item
0     2    h
1     3    c
2     3    d
3     3    e
4     3    g
5     4    a
6     4    i
```